# Controller 'new' action with two pages, rendering the second page if fails to save

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

my `def new` action in my controller does two actions. The first action selects a customer, and then upon selecting we go to another page and add further information on this page.

my class name is `content_text`. In the first page I am trying to assign it a customer, and in the second page i am

When I am at the first page my url looks like

```
/site_content/new?source_content_text_id=20
```

When I get to the second page I have params in my url and it looks similar to

```
/new?utf8=✓&customer_id=2&source_content_text_id=20&commit=Set+Customer
```

My problem is, if there is an issue with my form, and my class won't save, I am rendering `:new`.  But this takes me to the first page, and i'd like to get it so that it renders the second new page instead.

This is my controller action.

```
  def create
    @content_text.content_area = @source_content_text.content_area

    if @content_text.save
      redirect_to [@content_text], notice: 'Content Text was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

When I try to sub the `render :new` with

```
  render 'new?utf8=✓&customer_id=2&source_content_text_id=20&commit=Set+Customer'
```

I get a `Missing template` error.

Is it possible to do what I am hoping to do?

Comment: Can you share your controller's `new` method

Comment: How does new know to render the second page the first time around?